# How to pronounce "fe" as in "the fe programming language"?

Tags: terminology

[fe](https://fe-lang.org/) is an EVM programming language. How do you pronounce it?

Comment: Fe as in ferrum? Iron.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no official stance on the pronunciation. The name Fe comes from the chemical element for iron. I work on the core Fe team and initially I tried to pronounce it like the German word "[Fee](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Fee)"  (IPA `[feː]`) (fairy in English) . But most people pronounce it like the English word ["fee"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fee) (IPA `: /fiː/`) and that's what I also mostly use now because it goes easier over my tongue when speaking in English. Having said that, there are no rules, feel free to pronounce it any way you want.